# How to run FSCK with write capabilities on a sever with 4+ partitions

Tags: server, mount, hard-drive, fsck

I wanted to know how to run the `fsck` command on a server with write capabilities. 
The command should run structurally from one hard disk partition to another without any user interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of filesystem you are using. Ext2/3/4, for example, cannot safely run on a mounted filesystem, so you must either boot into single user mode, or use a boot disk. Other types allow mounted checks in writemode (btrfs, etc.).

Comment: Its Ext3 and on a SATA drive